# SwiftUI: TextField selectedTextRange doesn't work if tapped outside existing text in the field

Tags: ios, swiftui, cursor, textfield

Goal: I have a number textfield and I am trying to set cursor to end of position when tapped
Issue: If user taps outside the existing text in textfield, cursor position will not change. However, if user taps on already existing text, it works.

Here is the code and video. Can someone please tell me How I can fix this ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sourceVal: Double = 100.0
    @FocusState var focusedField: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("hide keyboard")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("sai hide keyboard")
                        self.focusedField = nil
                    }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Enter Value: ")
                    .font(.title3.bold())
                TextField(String(sourceVal), value: $sourceVal, format: .number)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: "Source")
                    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { obj in
                        print("yes tapped on me")
                        if let textField = obj.object as? UITextField {
                            print("trying to set it")
                            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a temporary solution.  setting it on main thread in next frame seems to work
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
         textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
}`
`